# Preventing symbology reclassification from adding 0s to Range in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology

How do I prevent symbology's "Natural Breaks" from automatically changing my range to include multiple 0s after my decimals?

Example: Range was originally 1 - 249. I switched to Natural Breaks and the range is now 1.0000000000 - 250.00000, then 250.0000001 - x. It should be 251.

In Range my counts now have just enough zeros to make both columns have the exact same number of digits and line up perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to change this globally. The added decimals are the results of your raster data having a too big precision value.

Nevertheless, removing the decimals from the labels manually per raster layer is quite simple.
Click on the `Label` header, then select the `Format Labels..` item. 
There round down to 0 the number of decimals place, and voilà
 [image]

Comment: Thank you. That does work for the Labels. I would still like to change the Range to not include 0s. I have used the same data set for other maps and this has never happened. I am also using all whole numbers, so precision was never an issue. Ex. 2852.00001-12287.0000 then 12287.0001-x, I would not know which category the count of 12287 would go into.